# Eventos en django

Tags: django, django-models, model

quisiera crear eventos en Django cuando se guarde, se guarde en otra tabla cuando se creo y cosas asi, si es para borrar que se guarde en otra tabla cuando se borro, como medidas de seguridad puesto que al usuario siempre se le pregunta y nunca hizo nada cuando borro información de la base de datos

Comment: Quizás [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) te sea de ayuda.

Comment: y para acciones con registros por ej   nombre=maria vive=España pero actualizado nombre=maria vive=US (REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO), pero tambien REGISTRO ANTERIOR nombre=maria vive=España

Comment: Te pueden servir las señales... pero no estas especificando lo que realmente quieres hacer...

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas llevan un registro completo de las acciones que realiza el usuario, editar crear, borrar, etc. Te recomiendo el paquete django-auditlog

Puedes ver un poco mas de el aqui:

```
https://github.com/jazzband/django-auditlog
```

Si das mas detalles de cual es tu objetivo puedo completar la respuesta con alguna otra sugerencia.

Saludos